# Weird (to me) behavior of increment (+=) operator for lists

Tags: python, increment, pascals-triangle

The following code works and gives `L` as the first `N` lines in Pascal's triangle:

```py
N = 5
L = [[]] * N
i = j = 0

while i < N:
  if j == 0 or j == i:
    a = 1
  else:
    a = L[i-1][j] + L[i-1][j-1]
  
  L[i] = L[i] + [a]  # ***

  if j < i:
    j += 1
  else:
    j = 0
    i += 1

[print(x) for x in L]
```

which gives, as expected,

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
```

But, if I replace the line marked with `# ***` by

```py
L[i] += [a]
```

it doesn't work anymore... It seems to append `[a]` to all sublists in `L`, and not just `L[i]`. Is there some behavior of the `+=` operator I'm missing? I don't get it, because the following code fragment works as expected:

```py
L = [[], []]
L[0] += [1]
L[1] += [2]
print(L)
```

resulting in `[[1], [2]]`

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
L[i] += [a]
```

corresponds to

```
L[i].extend([a])
```

and is a *mutation on the existing list* and thus **not equivalent** to:

```
L[i] = L[i] + [a]
```

where the evaluation of the right hand side will create a *new* list object and bind that new object to `L[i]`.

Mutating lists in in `L` would affect all of them, because `L = [[]] * N` creates a list of N references to one and the same (empty) list object.

In general in Python, the equivalence

```
a = a + b  <==> a += b
```

can only be safely assumed for immutable types.

Comment: It's also important to realize that `L = [[]] * N` creates N of the *same* list, so a modification to one affects all of them.